# jTypeWriter jquery used in PHP, how to type one line at a time?

Tags: jquery

I am using jTypeWriter  jquery in a php.
This jquery is getting its text from a txt file that contains many sentences each one end with a period.

The problem is : I want the jquery to start typing from the beginning each time the sentence in the file is finished, and then move to the next one and so on. I want that to be a loop.

I tried inserting break tag at the end of the sentence in the text file but that dosent help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-container").jTypeWriter({
        sequential: false,
        loop: true,
        loopDelay: 5,
        duration: 6
    });
});​
</script>
```

The jquery server is maybe down but I found the code here :http://pastebin.com/W85XGWcV
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: No code provided ? And top of all the jQuery plugins section is down for maintenance, how are we supposed to help then ?

Comment: The jquery server is maybe down but I found the code here :http://pastebin.com/W85XGWcV ,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, maybe you should try another plugin/script. I spent some time to get a workaround. Well with this script you cannot define the speed, if you want, you can try it on your own! The solution that I found is using another version of jTypeWriter that I found somewhere on the net (I'm not sure if it's the latest: [http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~kratsg/Scripts/TypewriterEffect/demo.html](http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/%7Ekratsg/Scripts/TypewriterEffect/demo.html))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~kratsg/Scripts/TypewriterEffect/jQuery.typewriter.min.js"></script>    <!-- PLEASE REMOVE THIS AND ADD A PATH TO YOUR OWN SERVER TO PREVENT directlinking) -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function writing(){
        $('#mycontainer').jTypewriter('type').delay(5000);  // sleep for 5 seconds after 1 loop
        setTimeout("writing()");
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            writing();
        });
        
    </script>

<div id="mycontainer">
    <?php
        $file = file_get_contents("text.txt");
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);
        foreach($lines as $line){
            echo "$line<br/>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi HamZa DzCyberDeV.<br/> Thanks for your reply. But I can't test it unless I have the actual jquery plugin , I couldn't find it on the net.<br/>.

Comment: Well, you can test it by copy&past the code above, and don't forget to create text.txt with some random text in it, the jquery plugin is downloaded from an external link http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~kratsg/Scripts/TypewriterEffect/jQuery.typewriter.min.js

Comment: Sorry about the website going down... I've put the original code back up here: https://giordonstark.com/jTypeWriter/ . At some point, I'll migrate this to a git repository so it's at least much publicly available.